# Mongodb not Connected only Waiting for connection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am new in MongoDB And I installed MongoDB successfully in window 64bit.

Before few days MongoDB Connected Successfully But Currently it is not Connected.

MongoDB installed location is:-

```
  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
```

I already put this location into environment variable.

then I created the directory

```
C:\Users\Ahmad\data\db
```

Now I want to connection with mongoDB using

```
C:\Users\Ahmad>mongod --dbpath C:\Users\Ahmad\data\db
```

then some code is generating

```
2016-12-06T12:15:43.735+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3
160 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Users\Ahmad\data\db 64-bit host=Shahzad
2016-12-06T12:15:43.736+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/W
indows Server 2008 R2
2016-12-06T12:15:43.736+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-12-06T12:15:43.736+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c
977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2016-12-06T12:15:43.736+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-12-06T12:15:43.737+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-12-06T12:15:43.737+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-12-06T12:15:43.737+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-12-06T12:15:43.737+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ss
l
2016-12-06T12:15:43.737+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-12-06T12:15:43.738+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-12-06T12:15:43.738+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { db
Path: "C:\Users\Ahmad\data\db" } }
2016-12-06T12:15:43.739+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C
:\Users\Ahmad\data\db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the
 active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-12-06T12:15:43.740+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config:
create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=fals
e,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snapp
y),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),stati
stics_log=(wait=0),
2016-12-06T12:15:44.467+0530 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Startin
g hostname canonicalization worker
2016-12-06T12:15:44.467+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time d
iagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/Users/Ahmad/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-12-06T12:15:44.473+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections
on port 27017
```

But connection is not established only **waiting for connections
    on port 27017** message is showing I waited long time but nothing is happening,

Comment: have you started your mongodb service ?
In windows you need to start if manually with a part where you have kept your mongodb data folder

Comment: Its successfully started, now if you want to connect, open new terminal window and execute `mongo` command

Answer (score 0):

copy bin and create new data repository into another drive and make sure that not allocate with OS boot files.
and then `C:\Users\Ahmad\data\db\mongod --dbpath C:\Users\Ahmad\data\db`

after run this line show you confirmation dialog from firewall proxy.